# Is it possible to use WinRT XAML Toolkit with WPF?

Tags: wpf, nuget-package, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I try to install using `Visual Studio Package Manager Console` and got this error:

> Install failed. Rolling back... Install-Package : Could not install
>   package 'WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Gauge 1.6.1.3'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files  that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Install-Package WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Gau

Answer (score 0):

Not as a NuGet package, I think you'd need a WPF Toolkit (of some sort).

WinRT XAML Toolkit is based on CoreCLR, not on the full .NET 4.5.

You can use the source code with very minor modifications though (mostly in namespaces). It depends on which part of the toolkit you need.

Check out the source at https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit

Comment: Well then you just need two files. Getting the whole think would be an overkill.
You need to put the cs file anywhere (and fix up namespaces) and get the control template into the generic.xaml file in your WPF app's Themes folder. The cs file is [here](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Gauge.UWP/Gauge.cs) and the XAML is [here](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Gauge.UWP/Themes/Generic.xaml)

Comment: 1. Create simple Class and put the .cs inside ?  2. create ResourceDictionary and give it the name Generic ?

Comment: Exactly so. _______________________

Comment: And what about all this using that missing: using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;

Comment: Added several quite different using and now in the line: OnValueChanged(this, null); got an error: Error 110 Argument 2: cannot convert from '<null>' to 'System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs'

Comment: Remove the WinRT usings and resolve missing references using Alt+Shift+F10. As for the dependency property change handlers - you should check out what the WPF syntax is.